# Fisher exact test run on multiple columns and results printed to a separate table

Tags: r

I am working with a data frame containing case control status, participant ID and genotype data for a SNP per column.

```
caco   ID     x132267464     x132270331   ...
1      10125  0/1            0/0          ...
2      10202  0/2            0/0          ...
...
```

I wish to run a fisher exact test on the case control (caco) and the genotype data for each snp, once the fisher test is run I want to save the P value to a separate table.

So a fisher test for caco v x132267464, the p value and odds ratio printed to row 1 of the result table, then caco v x132270331 with the p value and odds ratio printed to row 2 and so on.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you need a start, you could try http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18558/fishers-exact-test-in-r.

Answer (score 0):

Actually managed to solve the problem my code looks like this

```
c <- 3 
i <- 1
p <- 1
data <- data.frame()

while (i < 123 ) {    

  TAB <- table(acadfull$caco, acadfull[,c])      
  ANS <- fisher.test(TAB, conf.int=T)


  c <- c+1  
  i <- i+1
  p <- p+1

  if (i==123)
  break

}

write.csv(c(snp,pos,data),"indel_results", row.names=F)
```